# Border around each of two columns in landscape

Tags: two-column, landscape, border, fancybox

I am trying to create a document in landscape with two columns (portrait) and borders around each column.

Here is what I am using

```
\documentclass[12pt,landscape,twocolumn,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\begin{document}
\fancypage{\fbox}{}

My text here.

\end{document}
```

The problem I am having is that it puts a border around the whole page rather than each column.  Thoughts?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Well, `\fancypage` does use the whole page, it does not care about the two columns

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!  Please take a moment to take our [Tour](http://tex.stackexchange.com/tour)!  You may also want to look at what makes a good Minimal Working Example ([MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that))

Answer (score 1):

One solution using `flowfram`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,bmargin=2cm,paperheight=9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{flowfram}
\newflowframe*[all]{.47\textwidth}{\textheight}{0em}{0em}[colA]
\newflowframe*[all]{.47\textwidth}{\textheight}{.51\textwidth}{0em}[colB]
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{document}
```

Another (quite different) with `tcolorbox`, that could more convenient if you want more than a simple frame:

```
\documentclass[a5paper,twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage[latin]{babel}
\usepackage[margin=1cm,bmargin=2cm,paperheight=9cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\begin{tcolorbox}[breakable, 
colback=white, colframe=black, 
sharp corners,boxsep=0pt]
\lipsum[1-10]
\end{tcolorbox}
\end{document}
```